# Throttling of Microsoft Graph threat assessment API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

I'm starting to use Microsoft Graph threat assessment API to report Phishing Website URL.
(Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/informationprotection-post-threatassessmentrequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

My use-case is automatic reporting and manual reporting via Slack Command.
But throttling is very strict, so I get "429" response immediately.

```
    "code": "ActivityLimitReached",
    "message": "The client application has been throttled for reaching an activity limit. The request may be repeated after a delay, the length of which may be specified in a 'Retry-After' header.",
```

Does anyone know a workaround for the throttling?
As far as I confirmed, throttling is `1 request per 15 minutes (Limit per resource)` by default.
(`150 requests per 15 minutes (Limit per tenant)` though)

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#information-protection

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following best practice to avoid/handle the throttling.

When you implement error handling, use the HTTP error code 429 to detect throttling. The failed response includes the Retry-After response header. Backing off requests using the Retry-After delay is the fastest way to recover from throttling because Microsoft Graph continues to log resource usage while a client is being throttled.

1. Wait the number of seconds specified in the Retry-After header.
2. Retry the request.
3. If the request fails again with a 429 error code, you are still being throttled. Continue to use the recommended Retry-After delay and retry the request until it succeeds.

The guidelines for throttling is already [provided by Microsoft Graph team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) and it's straightforward. Please go through this doc, look out for best practices to avoid throttling, to handle throttling etc and think about throttling/batching to see if it suits your scenario (so you can optimize the calls).

If retry-after header doesnt exists then it would be tough - thats the way to handle throttling, unless if any alternate way exists provided. If you still believe Microsoft to implement this feature, consider creating a [new user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359617).

Update: @rung created [a new uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41991061-increase-throttling-of-threat-assessment-api) on this.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, you can't get Retry-After header from threat assessment API's 429 error, and the throttling itself is too strict about reporting phishing immediately.
So I would like to know a workaround. (if there is no workaround in the api, I might make enough user in the same tenant to report phishing only.)

Comment: If retry-after header doesnt exists then it would be tough - thats the way to handle throttling, unless if any alternate way exists provided. If you still believe Microsoft to implement this feature, consider creating a new user voice at - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359617

Comment: Thank you so much. make sense, I'll ask it for now.

Comment: Cool. I updated the above answer as well. Once you can create user voice, feel free to share it here. So it can be useful to others as well.

Comment: Thank you for your navigation. I added user voice https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41991061-increase-throttling-of-threat-assessment-api

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing..!!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the similar use case. I am planning to submit the Msg Id/URL/file to Microsoft for phishing assessment using API . I am stuck with an error that shows " "code": "Unauthorized",

```
"message": "Required authentication information is either missing or not valid for the resource.",
```

"

I would highly appreciate your help!